# Error in data.frame(data, index) : variable 'country' does not exist

Tags: r, csv, plm

I am trying to run very simple fixed effect model on a small data set. Sample data set is rather small. I loaded the data via a csv file and then ran plm command. But i am running into an error and i am not able to figure out reason.
My csv file looks like this:

```
country,year,y,x1
A,2000,6.0,7.8
A,2001,4.6,0.6
A,2002,9.4,2.1
```

Following is the set of commands i ran on console:

```
>test<-read.table("test.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
head(test)
fixed <- plm(y ~ x1,data=test,index=c("country","year"),model="within")
series country is constant and has been removed
Error in pdata.frame(data, index) : variable country does not exist
```

I am using [this](http://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Panel101R.pdf) as a reference to understand how to work with fixed and random effect model in R. When i followed the instruction mentioned in this ppt and ran `plm()` using there data set, i was able to get correct results.
Thanks!

Comment: what does your `head(test)` print out? also `summary(test)`

Comment: it prints out:
  <br>country year   y  x1
<br>1       A 2000 6.0 7.8
<br>2       A 2001 4.6 0.6
<br>3       A 2002 9.4 2.1

Comment: it prints out correct results

Comment: have you tried:
`ptest <- pdata.frame(test, index=c("country", "year"))`

Comment: I assume you have more than one country in your data? If not, that is the problem.

Comment: If you figured out the problem, please post the answer so others will have access to it and the question won't be left open.

Answer (score 0):

I added one more country to my sample data set and it seems to work..so now the data looks like this:

```
<br>country,year,y,x1
<br>A,2000,6.0,7.8
<br>A,2001,4.6,0.6
<br>A,2002,9.4,2.1
<br>B,2000,5.0,7.2
<br>B,2001,5.6,0.9
<br>B,2002,8.1,3.4
```